# Remove Duplicate Dependencies in Maven Pom

Tags: linux, windows, maven, netbeans, notepad++

I would like to remove duplicate dependencies in maven pom.xml.

I would like answers to multiple tools Linux, Notepad++, Netbeans, Intellij ...even...VIM,etc.

example (I can obvious delete but I would like a search replace answer)

```
  `<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>`
```

Please write the answer locally links can be frustrating if removed. Thanks.

Comment: The generic best-practice solution would obviously be to avoid adding duplicate dependencies in the first place. Once you've reached the point where you have enough `pom.xml` with duplicate dependencies that you can't handle them manually, I'm really not sure the cost of developing a custom solution to remove them is worth the probably low cost of leaving them and/or correcting them as you find them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run
     mvn clean 
It will tell you your duplicate dependencies. Then delete them.

Comment: I would still like to see multiline find replace options but this is about spot on.

Comment: How does one delete them?

Answer (score 11):

dependency:analyze-duplicate Analyzes the  and  tags in the pom.xml and determines the duplicate declared dependencies.

```
mvn dependency:analyze-duplicate
```

Comment: This is an awesome command, and really helpful to find dupes. I with there was some automation or a plugin that actually prunes them for you, akin to https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn-deduplicate.

Answer (score 9):

you can use `mvn dependency:tree` command to find duplicate dependencies into your project.

Use the `<exclusions>` tag into `<dependency>` tag of the pom to exclude that duplicate dependencies from maven project.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>test.ProjectX</groupId>
      <artifactId>ProjectX</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  
          <groupId>test.ProjectY</groupId>
          <artifactId>ProjectY</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the pom.xml is XML you can also use XSLT:

1. Go to https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html
2. Use this XSLT:

   ```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
       <dependencies>
           <xsl:for-each-group select="dependency" group-by="concat(groupId , '|', artifactId)">
               <xsl:sequence select="."/>
           </xsl:for-each-group>
       </dependencies>
   </xsl:template>

   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
3. Cut the `<dependencies>` section from you pom.xml as input
4. Paste the output of the XSLT back into your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

mvn dependency:list -Dsort=true |
grep "^[INFO]    " |
awk '{print $2}' |
cut -f1-4 -d: |
sort |
uniq |
cut -f1-3 -d: |
uniq -c |
grep -v '^ *1 '